# How to make a combobox in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, combobox, uipickerview

I am trying to make a combobox in ios following this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/iPhone/iphonecombobox.aspx.
But the click event (that shows the picker) seems to work sometimes and sometimes not. It looks like sometimes it just works in some regions of the control and not others.

Any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: Please post the code related to the problem? Is this something you have created or something you found online and are trying to modify?

Comment: @Tony why not using the feedback functionality on codeproject.com and ask the original author?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, the answer was using the textfield and image directly to the page instead of creating a view for the control and using that view N times.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of hacky, but you can add a hidden `UIControl` around the region of the ComboBox and then wire it up to the same `IBAction` or `void` that the existing ComboBox uses. For example,  `-(IBAction) showPicker` could be the action of a new `UIControl` that you add right around the region.

Answer (score 0):

I created a combobox api for iOS, hope this could be of any help: http://www.chupamobile.com/products/details/365/ZComboBox/

Comment: If it was free I would give it a shot

Comment: Or even if there was a video demo, otherwise not worth paying for something that might not work.